# How can I get cumulative measure of data in increasing fashion

Tags: graph, plot, statistics, probability

I have a data with two columns like following

**Column_1 , Column_2**

1 , 0.474124203822

2 , 0.545760430686

3 , 0.614420062696

4 , 0.654518950437

5 , 0.696226415094

6 , 0.6875

For simplicity, you can consider the data like 
*Column_2 = Probability of success when (X=column_1)*
The relationship is somewhat increasing. Now If I just plot the data upto 30 points as a line graph I will obtain the following

[image]

Now, my question is how can I plot my data in a cumulative fashion (using what measure) like the following simple example

**col_1(age) , col_2(Total cumulative number of people <= age)**

10 , 200

20 , 1000

30 , 5000

Please let me know if my description is not clear enough or you have additional question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your probability mass function, you can compute the cumulative mass function as follows.

```
// Probability mass function
pmf = [0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3]

// Cumulative mass function
cmf = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

cmf[0] = pmf[0]
for i = 1, 2, 3, 4
    cmf[i] = cmf[i - 1] + pmf[i]
```

Now simply plot your cumulative mass function instead of your probability mass function.